# How to extract multiple specific string lines from another string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm using a FEM software (Code_Aster) which is developed in Python, but its file extension is `.comm`. However, Python snippets can be inserted in `.comm` files.

I have a function which returns a very long `string` containing `nodes`, `elements`, `elements group`, and so on in the below form:

[image]

My goal is to add each row to a list/dictionary with its associate coordinates or nodes. For example:

```py
dct_nodes = {
    'N5': [
        9.99999999998248E-03,
        0.00000000000000E+00,
        0.00000000000000E+00
    ]
}

dct_elems = {
    'M5': ['N1', 'N5'],
    'M85': ['N342', 'N224', 'N378']
}
```

I tried regex with `re.split`, `re.search`, and `re.findall` but I don't seem to be able to get what I need. This is what I've done so far.

```py
node_list = list()

for item in ttt.split("\n"):
    if len(item) != 0: # there are some lines with zero len
        if item[0] == 'N':
            node_list.append(re.sub("\s+", ",", item.strip()))
```

The `type(node_list[0])` returns `string`, whereas I would like to have a nested list, so I can grab `node_list[0][0]` and `node_list[0][1]` for data manipulation. How can I split this string on `,` so I can have access to, for examples, the coordinates. I hope anyone can help.

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other lines starting with `N` or `M`, the below script does the job perfectly.

```py
import re

ttt="""
%
COOR_3D
N1      0       0       0
N2      1       5       9
N3      2       6       10
N4      3       7       11
N5      4       8       12

FINSF
%
SEG2
M1      N1      N2
M2      N3      N4
FINSF
%
TRIA3
M3      N5      N6      N7
M4      N8      N9      N11
M5      N12     N13     N14"""


def finder(var,string):
    temp_dic = dict()
    for item in string.split("\n"):
        if len(item) != 0: # there are some lines with zero len
            temp = re.sub("\s+", ",", item.strip()).split(',')
            if item[0] == var:
                temp_dic[temp[0]] = [e for e in temp[1:]]
    return temp_dic

                
nodes = finder('N',ttt)
elems = finder('M',ttt)
```

Please also note that if you need to do arithmetic manipulations on the coordinates of the nodes, you have to cast them to `float` because they are `string` yet. You can probably use a tertiary operator to decide if `e` should be cast to a `float` or remains a `string`. I hope you find this answer useful.

Comment: Thank you very much! It did the job and saved me a lot of time.